# Filter rows based on a threshold by grouping ID column

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, dplyr

I have a data frame that I got from

```
ID <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C") 
Type <- c(45,46,47,45,46,47,45,46,47)
Point_A <- c(10,15,20,8,9,10,35,33,39) 
df <- data.frame(ID,Type,Point_A)

    ID  Type    Point_A 
1   A   45        10    
2   A   46        15    
3   A   47        20    
4   B   45        8    
5   B   46        9    
6   B   47        10    
7   C   45        35    
8   C   46        33    
9   C   47        39
```

I want to calculate the median of the Point_A column grouping by ID and then remove the rows based on a threshold.

For example, lets say my **threshold is 11**. I want to remove the rows grouped by ID having median less than the threshold and so the desired output would be

```
    ID  Type    Point_A 
1   A   45        10    
2   A   46        15    
3   A   47        20    
4   C   45        35    
5   C   46        33    
6   C   47        39
```

While I am able to calculate the medians but I am not knowing how to remove the rows.

```
func <- function(x) (median(x,na.rm=TRUE))
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(.=func(.)),Point_A) 
  summarise(Point_A = f(Point_A))
```

Kindly let me know how to go about doing this.

Comment: These questions have been asked SO MANY times.. please search under data.table and/or dplyr tags..

Comment: As Arun mentioned you may find this in `subset` or `filter` questions in `dplyr`.  If you were not successful, try  `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(median(Point_A, na.rm=TRUE)>11)` and for `data.table`. `setDT(df)[,if(median(Point_A, na.rm=TRUE) > 11) .SD, ID]`

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I got it working on a larger dataset as well. 
Arun, I apologize for asking silly questions. I will look up carefully the tags before asking.